# When is Fisher's z-transform appropriate?

Tags: correlation, sample-size, fisher-transform

I want to test a sample correlation $r$ for significance, using p-values, that is

$H_0: \rho = 0, \; H_1: \rho \neq 0.$

I have understood that I can use Fisher's z-transform to calculate this by

$z_{obs}= \displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{n-3}}{2}\ln\left(\displaystyle\frac{1+r}{1-r}\right)$

and finding the p-value by

$p = 2P\left(Z>z_{obs}\right)$

using the standard normal distribution.

My question is: how large $n$ should be for this to be an appropriate transformation? Obviously, $n$ must be larger than 3. My textbook does not mention any restrictions, but on slide 29 of [this presentation](http://courses.education.illinois.edu/EdPsy580/lectures/correlation-ha.pdf) it says that $n$ must be larger than 10. For the data I will be considering, I will have something like $5 \leq n \leq 10$.

Comment: The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_transformation) lists the standard error of $z_{obs}$ which is given by $1/\sqrt{N-3}$ where $N$ is the sample size. So you'll need at least 4 complete pairs. I'm not aware of any restrictions beyond that regarding sample size.

Comment: Not sure how much to trust a presentation from someone who can't spell their own university name. More seriously, beware all advice that implies that things are fine above a certain sample size and dire otherwise. It's a matter of approximation quality increasing smoothly with sample size and also depending on the distribution of the data. Simple advice is to be very cautious, plot everything and cross-check with bootstrapped confidence intervals.

Comment: Slide 17 describes a t-test for the special case $\rho=0$.

Comment: The link to a presentation at  http://courses.education.illinois.edu/EdPsy580/lectures/correlation-ha.pdf is now broken,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For questions like these I would just run a simulation and see if the $p$-values behave as I expect them to. The $p$-value is the probability of randomly drawing a sample that deviates at least as much from the null-hypothesis as the data you observed if the null-hypothesis is true. So if we had many such samples, and one of them had a $p$-value of .04 then we would expect 4% of those samples to have a value less than .04. The same is true for all other possible $p$-values.

Below is a simulation in Stata. The graphs check whether the $p$-values measure what they are supposed to measure, that is, they shows how much the proportion of samples with $p$-values less than the nominal $p$-value deviates from the nominal $p$-value. As you can see that test is somewhat problematic with such small number of observations. Whether or not it is too problematic for your research is your judgement call.

```
clear all
set more off

program define sim, rclass
    tempname z se
    foreach i of numlist 5/10 20(10)50 {
        drop _all
        set obs `i'
        gen x = rnormal()
        gen y = rnormal()
        corr x y 
        scalar `z'  = atanh(r(rho))
        scalar `se' = 1/sqrt(r(N)-3)
        return scalar p`i' = 2*normal(-abs(`z'/`se'))
    }
end

simulate p5 =r(p5)  p6 =r(p6)  p7  =r(p7)     ///
         p8 =r(p8)  p9 =r(p9)  p10 =r(p10)    ///
         p20=r(p20) p30=r(p30) p40 =r(p40)    ///
         p50=r(p50), reps(200000) nodots: sim 

simpplot p5 p6 p7 p8 p9 p10, name(small, replace) ///
    scheme(s2color) ylabel(,angle(horizontal))
```

[image]

```
simpplot p20 p30 p40 p50 , name(less_small, replace) ///
    scheme(s2color) ylabel(,angle(horizontal))
```

[image]

Comment: Try subtracting 2.5 instead of 3 from $n$ :-).

Answer (score 7):

FWIW I see the recommendation $N\ge 10$ in Myers & Well (research design and statistical analyses, second edition, 2003, p. 492). The footnote states:

> Strictly speaking, the $Z$ transformation is biased by an amount $r/(2(N-1))$: see Pearson and Hartley (1954, p. 29). This bias will generally be negligible unless $N$ is small and $\rho$ is large, and we ignore it here.

Comment: This does seem like it is an answer to me.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether a Fisher's $z$ transform is appropriate here. For $H_0: \rho=0$ (NB: null hypothesis is for population $\rho$, not sample $r$), the sampling distribution of the correlation coefficient is already symmetric, so no need to reduce skewness, which is what Fisher's $z$ aims to do, and you can use Student's $t$ approximation.

Assuming you mean $H_0: \rho = \rho_0 \not = 0$, then the skewness of that PDF will depend on the proposed value of $\rho_0$, so there would then be no general answer of how large $n$ should be. Also, minimum values of $n$ would depend on the significance level $\alpha$ that you are working toward. You did not state its value.

Nick's point is a fair one: the approximations and recommendations are always operating in some grey area.

If, then, your Fisher approximation is good (=symmetric) enough, I would use the bound $n\geq (t_{\alpha/2} s/\epsilon)^2$ applicable to $t$-distributions, where $s$ is the sample standard deviation. If it is close enough to normality, this becomes $n \geq (1.96 s/\epsilon)^2$.

Comment: I think this oversimplifies the "aim" of Fisher's $z$, which is partly a matter of purpose as well as mathematics. Skewness or not is only part of the picture; $z$ transforms a bounded distribution to an unbounded one, which is important for confidence intervals. In fact, I would argue that unless a null hypothesis of zero correlation is the scientific question too, the use of Fisher's $z$ for confidence intervals is much more fruitful than trying to get a P-value.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am new to the Fisher's $z$-transform. Should I only use it if I want to test $H_0: \rho = \rho_0 \neq 0$? The reason for calculating P-values is that I want to use the Holm-Bonferroni method to control family-wise error rate when doing multiple comparisons. Should I rather calculate P-values from a Student's $t $ distribution?

Comment: Question is the wrong way round, I think. Fisher's $z$ is a better method for confidence intervals and for inference generally. Most software, I guess, uses a $t$-based calculation for testing $\rho = 0$. If in doubt it could be really important to show whether using one method makes a difference for your data. So, if methods agree, there is no problem.

Comment: You can read more about Fisher's $z$ transformation here: http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0041

Comment: Ok, thank you @NickCox! @Lucozade, what is the $\epsilon$ in the bound on $n$ ?