# Fisher's z-transform in Python?

Tags: correlation, sample-size, python, fisher-transform

I want to test a sample correlation $r$ for significance ($n=16$), using p-values, in Python. As I have understood from [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62824/when-is-fishers-z-transform-appropriate), I can achieve that by using Fisher's z-transform.

Is there a Python module, which allows easy use of Fisher's z-transform?

I have not been able to find the functionality in [SciPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) or [Statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html). So far, I have had to write my own messy temporary function:

```python
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import zprob
def z_transform(r, n):
    z = np.log((1 + r) / (1 - r)) * (np.sqrt(n - 3) / 2)
    p = zprob(-z)
    return p
```

Comment: AFAIK the Fisher transform equals the [inverse hyperbolic tangent](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arctanh.html), so just use that.

Comment: Presumably `z-transform` is a typo, since that's an invalid Python identifier (`-` is interpreted as subtraction).

Comment: This test assumes that you're sampling from a bivariate normal distribution.  Does that make sense here?  I'd prefer to do some sort of randomization test and approximate the null distribution using simulation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Fisher transform equals the inverse hyperbolic tangent‌​/arctanh, which is implemented for example in [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arctanh.html). The inverse Fisher transform/tanh can be dealt with [similarly](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tanh.html).

Moreover, [numpy's function for Pearson's correlation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html#scipy.stats.pearsonr) also gives a *p* value.

Comment: The [`pearsonr()` function in numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html#scipy.stats.pearsonr) is "only reasonable for datasets larger than 500".

Comment: [Reading the sources](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/stats/stats.py#L2392), numpy uses the *t* score to test the significance of the correlation. I'm not aware of this approach being especially problematic.

Comment: Check if the *p*-values from pearsonr() and the z-transformed approach are similar!

Comment: Both `pearsonr` and `np.arctanh` take only a single row or column array as input, not arrays with more than one row or column.

Comment: To test the significance of the difference between two correlation coefficients, r1 and r2, how can i do that? I need to first convert r-to-z and then take the difference to see the z-score effect size?