# Why t-test of correlation coefficient can't be used for testing non-zero?

Tags: correlation, t-test, z-test

**t-test of a correlation coefficient** is used for testing the sample correlation against population correlation of zero. To test an assumed value of the population coefficient other than zero, we should use **z-test for a correlation coefficient**.

**Question:**

1. What makes the tests different such that the t-test can only test for zero? Isn't the z-test a special case of the t-test (infinite degree of freedom)?
2. Since the t-test can't be used for tested for non-zero correlation. Why can't we always use the z-test? What's the point of the t-test?

**EDITED for reference:**

**100 Statistical Tests by Gopal K.Janji**

[image]

Comment: I have not heard this before, do you have a source? (I may just be ignorant!)

Comment: @GeoMatt22 I added a reference, please look at Limitations.

Comment: These might be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#Testing_using_Student.27s_t-distribution and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#Using_the_Fisher_transformation . I am assuming the latter has been done in _Test 13_ your text is referring to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is Fisher's z-transform appropriate?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62824/when-is-fishers-z-transform-appropriate)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: You don't use a t-test of the depicted form when $\rho\neq 0$ simply because the statistic $\frac{r\sqrt{n-2}}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}$ has a $t_{n-2}$ distribution when $\rho= 0$ (and the other assumptions hold) and it doesn't have a $t_{n-2}$ distribution otherwise.

There's several different z-tests for a correlation coefficient (whether $\rho$ is $0$ or not), but they're approximate, large sample tests. Some approximations are better than others. It may be that you can also make a good t approximation, but I don't recall seeing a derivation of any that would give you a suitable $\nu$.