# Comparing dependent correlations

Tags: correlation, cross-correlation, intraclass-correlation

I have a simple single-group pre-post design and have Pearson correlations for *performance* and *self-report* for both times of measurement for each participant that I would like to compare.

Would using a paired t-test be appropriate or would another test be better, as correlations are in themselves statistics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A paired $t$-test should work OK. There is no particular problem with using statistics you have derived from data as input to a fresh analysis. One thing you might want to do is to transform them using Fisher's $z$ transformation so that they are better distributed. There is more about that transformation here [When is Fisher's z-transform appropriate?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62824/when-is-fishers-z-transform-appropriate) or in a number of internet sources.

Answer (score 2):

Use Williams's Test (dependent, overlapping) or Steiger Tests (dependent, non-overlapping) for comparing correlation coefficients based on one sample.

See

> Steiger, J.H. (1980), Tests for comparing elements of a correlation matrix, Psychological Bulletin, 87, 245-251.

R-Implementations can be found in the `psych` and `cocor` packages.